# Laravel Edit forms shows blank screen first load

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel Crud operation

When i open the edit option initially from button link it shows me blank screen as attached in both browser Chrome and FireFox

But when i reload it from the URL by hitting enter it loads the screen

Also when i save the form it return me the GIF image in ajax response.
the module name is advertisement

Is there possibilities the word advertisement can cause the issue?

[image]

**AdvtController.php**

```
public function edit($uuid)
{
    Languages::setBackLang();

    $checkPermission = Permissions::checkActionPermission('edit_advertisement');
    if ($checkPermission == false) {
        return view('backend.access-denied');
    }

    $advertisementData = Advertisement::loadAdvertise($uuid, Languages::EN);
    if (empty($advertisementData)) {
        Helper::log('Advertisement edit : No record found');
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', trans('backend/common.oops'));
    }

    $languages = Languages::where('language_id', Languages::EN)->select('language_id', 'name')->first();
    $language_id = Languages::getBackLanguageId();

    return view('backend.advertisement.edit', compact('languages', 'advertisementData'));
}
```

**edit.blade.php**

```
    @extends('backend.layout')
@php
    $lang = \App\Models\Languages::getBackLang();
@endphp
@section('scripts')
    <script src="{{asset('backend/dist/js/jquery.validate.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('backend/dist/js/pages/custom.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('backend/dist/js/pages/advt.js')}}"></script>
@endsection

@section('content')
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <section class="content-header">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row mb-2">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <h1 class="m-0 text-dark">{{trans('backend/advertisement.advertisement')}}</h1>
                    </div><!-- /.col -->
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <ol class="breadcrumb {{($lang == 'ar') ? 'float-sm-left':'float-sm-right'}} ">
                            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a
                                        href="{{route('admin.home')}}">{{trans('backend/common.home')}}</a></li>
                            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a
                                        href="{{route('admin.advt.index')}}">{{trans('backend/advertisement.advertisement')}}</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="breadcrumb-item active">{{trans('backend/common.edit')}}</li>
                        </ol>
                    </div><!-- /.col -->
                </div><!-- /.row -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </section>

        <!-- /.content-header -->
        <section class="content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h3 class="card-title">{{trans('backend/advertisement.edit_advertisement')}}</h3>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.card-header -->
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div id="display_message" class="col-md-12 display-none">
                                <div class="alert display-none alert-success"></div>
                                <div class="alert display-none alert-danger"></div>
                            </div>
                            @include('backend.advertisement.form')
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.card-body -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.col -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
        </section>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Try to clear view cache and see if that helps. `php artisan view:clear` if not then find the template which gets loaded.